# Why this vue transformation doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to code simple slide panel, like here http://anton.shevchuk.name/wp-demo/jquery-tutorials/simple-slide-panel.html
but on Vue.js. But panel doesn't slide it's wait 2 seconds then close without animation.
https://codepen.io/TogusaRusso/pen/dqoMLr

If I remove v-if, I can animate it, changing height of div.
https://codepen.io/TogusaRusso/pen/mGJEEJ

How can I animate removing of div?

```
<template>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <transition name="slide" :duration="2000">
            <div
                class="slide-media"
                :style="{height: '400px'}"
                v-if="isOpen"
            >Hello!</div>
        </transition>
        <v-btn
            flat color="orange"
            @click="isOpen=!isOpen"
        >
            {{isOpen?"Close":"Open"}}
        </v-btn>
    </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'SlidePanel',
        data() {
            return {
                isOpen: false,
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
    .slide-media {
        background-color: orangered;
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
    .slide-enter-active, .slide-leave-active {
        transition: height 2s;
    }
    .slide-enter, .slide-leave-to {
        height: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: instead of `height`, try `max-height`

Comment: removed `:style="{height: '400px'}"` then added it to `.slide-media`, then it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check [MDN: Css Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types),

> **Inline styles** added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold")
>   **always overwrite** any styles **in external stylesheets**, and thus can be
>   thought of as having the highest specificity.

So removed the inline styles `:style="{height: '400px'}"`, then add `height:400px;` inside `.slide-media`.

Below is one demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      isOpen: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    togglePanel: function () {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.slide-media {
        background-color: orangered;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        height:400px;
    }
    .slide-enter-active, .slide-leave-active {
        transition: height 2s;
    }
    .slide-enter, .slide-leave-to {
        height: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="togglePanel()">Toggle Panel</button>
        <transition name="slide" :duration="2000">
            <div
                class="slide-media"

                v-if="isOpen"
            >Hello!</div>
        </transition>
</div>
```